# ggplot not showing points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to create a graph of various strains preferred light level for growth. My dataset is named "D" and my x axis should be "strain" and my y axis "light". I've tried the code

```
geom_point(data = D, aes(strain, light))
```

but when I plot this, the argument

```
mapping: x = ~strain, y = ~light 
geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
position_identity"
```

appears instead of a plot. I then tried

```
ggplot(D, aes(strain, light))
```

but then a graph shows up but without anything plotted. Any ideas for why this might be?

Comment: I provided an answer below that should work, but it would help if you can provide a minimally reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reformat your code:

```
ggplot(D, aes(x = strain, y = light)) +
geom_point()
```

This will get you to a basic plot, and then you can look at adding layers onto it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect the `ggplot()` call via `+` to the `geom_point()` call like this: `ggplot(D, aes(strain, light)) + geom_point()`